# Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'. Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I found alot of solutions but all didn't work for me.

I deleted android studio completely and flutter from windows, then download latest stable version of android studio and flutter.

**flutter doctor**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2486], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)      
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.3.4)
    X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++" workload, and include
      these components:
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
[√] VS Code (version 1.66.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

Also this didn't work!.

Comment: I'm not sure, but just try uninstalling java and reinstalling with the latest version.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: search java on windows (I believe you're on windows) and select uninstall option, uninstall it, then search java on browser, select the first site and download java and install it. (Still I'm not sure this solves the problem)

Answer (score 1):

Open your `app>gradle`

And change like

```
android {

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
```

[image]

now `flutter clean` and rebuild the app.

Also make sure you are using jdk11

[image]

Comment: how to be sure I am using jdk11?

Comment: You can use `java --version` on terminal or check environments variables on your computer.

Comment: from about java app this version: (build 1.8.0_361-b09)

Comment: search for installing java11/jdk11

Comment: is there a way to make it build on java 1.8

Comment: maybe not, I used to shift on 11 while having this error, check your file explorer, you might already have it, just need to change the env path

Comment: how can I find it in file explorer

Comment: follow https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+install+java+11+and+set+path+in+windows+10&rlz=1C1CHBF_enBD853BD853&sxsrf=AJOqlzWiTkTKjn9y5fTIMAq1Or6UxedIcQ%3A1676371602572&ei=kmbrY_e0IpWA9u8PwtOKkAI&oq=how+to+install+java11+and+set+en&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAxgAMggIABAIEB4QDTIFCAAQhgMyBQgAEIYDMgUIABCGAzIFCAAQhgM6CggAEEcQ1gQQsAM6BwgAEIAEEAo6CwgAEBYQHhDxBBAKOggIABAWEB4QCjoJCAAQFhAeEPEEOgsIABAIEB4QDRDxBDoGCAAQFhAeOgsIIRAWEB4Q8QQQHToFCAAQogQ6CggAEPEEEB4QogQ6BwghEKABEAo6CAghEBYQHhAdSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUJ8EWLccYM4qaAFwAXgAgAH-AogBkxeSAQYyLTEwLjGYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp